# is uni-directed graph constructed from bi-directed graph a DAG?

Tags: algorithm, graph, graph-theory, graph-algorithm, directed-acyclic-graphs

[image: bi-directional graph to uni directional graph]

For above graph.

```
for every vertex:
   remove back edge from children to it.
```

It think this will always result in a DAG but i'm not able to prove it.
is there any proof for it or can someone provide a counter argument?

Comment: nope, consider cycle of length > 2 e.g 1->2->3->1
there is no back edge from children, but still a cycle

Comment: @grodzi the initial graph is bi-directional, so the example in your case is similar to the example in image above.

Comment: The resulting graph seriously depends on the order of traversal. For example you may end up with a multiple disconnected components. That said, the absence of loops can be proven by a simple induction.

Answer (score 0):

Let `S` be the set of processed nodes.

#### Hypothesis

- `S` has no cycle.
- Any node of `S` has no backedge from children.

#### Initialization:

Add `1` to `S`.

- `1` has no backedge according to your alg
- it is not a cycle (does not loop to itself since no backedge)

#### Recurrence:

- No cycle:

Let `t` be the next node to add.
`S` is acyclic by hypothesis
To get a cycle in `S U {t}`, we need `t` to be in a cycle.

But `t` can't have an edge to any node `n` of `S`. Because if so, there exists a link from `n` to `t` (graph is originally undirected), which means `t` is a child of `n`. By your algorithm, when `n` was added to `S`, backedge from `t` has been removed.

Since there is is no edge from `t` to any node in `S`, there is no cycle involving `t` in `S U {t}`.

So `S U { t }` is still acyclic.

- No backedge:

All nodes in `S` are ok by hypothesis.

When adding `t`, the children of `t` have their backedge edge (to `t`) removed.

So `S U {t}` is still ok